# NowJS takes time to fire server events with more than 5 clients connected

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

I'm developing a multiplayer game in NodeJS with NowJS, the thing is when more than 5
clients are connected it starts to take more time:
First I thought I was doing bad processing on server side,
so I put a console.log first line on the everyone.[event] and the
weird thing it is taking time to call it, after that everything goes
in a second.

I have downloaded the quick 10 lines chat room example [here](http://www.nowjs.com/) and opened 6 mozilla tabs and it happends the same, it takes time **to fire the now event**, not to
distribute the message or process on server-side ... any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the version of NowJS & Node.js, please if you get this kind of error, try to update both to latest and put focus on what has been updated on the NowJS page.